# A silver cube has edge lenghts of 5 cm each. A stamp mark "800" indicates that...

Tags: volume

the cube is made of 800/1000 pure silver. Assume that silver has a density of 10.5 g/cm3 and a price of 0.68Euro/g. Calculate the value of the silver partion?

Haven't studied math since 15 years so I'd appreciate if someone could explain this question. Thanks in advance!

Comment: Rubik's cubes are usually made out of plastic.

Comment: If you know the edge length of a cube, what is it's volume? Use Google if necessary.

Comment: Usually the fraction that is silver represents the weight fraction, not the volume fraction.  In that case you do not have enough information to answer.

Answer (score 1):

Here are the steps along the way. YOu can do the arithmetic.

- Find the volume (in cubic centimeters) of the cube (use the side
  length)
- Find the volume that is silver (you're told the fraction of the
  whole) *(But if the given fraction is the weight fraction rather than the volume fraction you are stuck, as @RossMillikan comments,)*
- Find the weight of the silver (you know the density in grams per
  cubic centimeter)
- Find the value (you know the price in Euros per gram)